# Django: Store Q query objects for repeatable search?

Tags: python, django

In my Django based web app users can perform a search; the query consists of several dynamically constructed complex Q objects.

Depending on the user search parameters, the search will query a variable number of columns and also can stretch over multiple models.

The user should be able to save her search to repeat it at some later point.

For that I'd like to store the Q objects (I guess) in a database table.

Is this good practice? How would you approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could save the string/s the user wishes to search, and then just apply that string to the query whenever the user wishes to load a saved search. Just be careful of SQL Injection, Django should handle this for you if you do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one or a fixed number of `Q` objects as part of the filter, you can save the argument passed to `Q` as a dict.

.e.g This:

```py
Q(buy_book__entity__type=ENTITY.INTERNAL)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```py
q_filter = {"buy_book__entity__type": ENTITY.INTERNAL}
Q(**q_filter)
```

You can save `q_filter` in your datastore.

Comment: This could work but the Q queries are too complex. A simple q.deconstruct() would also not product json compatible output. I think I need some more code to properly serialize+json.dumps/json.loads+deserialize Q objects...